# How do I make a function field on an interface take the parameters of a corresponding function interface?

Tags: oop, generics, inheritance, typescript, interface

## Aim

I have a private function that takes two parameters:

```
export interface XhrHelperFunction extends Function {
    (cb ?: Function, lock ?: boolean) : any;
}
```

... and I have an interface for a public function that allows a user to invoke that private function:

```
export interface Actionable {
    run(cb : Function, lock?: boolean) : void;
}
```

The problem with this format is that each time I update the interface of `XhrHelperFunction`, I have to correspondingly update the format of my `Actionable` interface. Thus, I'd prefer to rewrite `Actionable` in a manner resembling: `run(/* Parameters of XhrHelperFunction */) : void;`

## Attempt

I've tried the following format:

```
export interface Actionable {
    run(XhrHelperFunction) : void;
}
```

This works when writing the `run` method signature within the class, but doesn't work when passing parameters into a class instance, ie. `actionable.run(cb, lock)` because apparently the parameters don't conform to the signature of `function run(XhrHelperFunction) : void`. I also can't wrap them in brackets and cast them to `XhrHelperFunction`.

What do you suggest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can introduce an argument type, e.g.

```
interface IArguments {
    cb? : Function;
    lock? : boolean;
}
```

and make your interfaces depend on this type:

```
export interface XhrHelperFunction extends Function {
    (args : IArguments) : any;
}

export interface Actionable {
    run(arguments : IArguments) : void;
}
```

I am wondering, why you don't make the helper function public in the first place, when you are exposing a very thin wrapper as public API. This would reduce the complexity of this interface. Note, that if you release your public interface it gets increasingly annoying to change the parameters of your function, as you'll need to change all places depending on the `Actionable` interface.

If you want to isolate the changes of the `XhrHelperFunction` from the consumers of your `Actionable` interface, then you can't expose the same argument type anyway and you should leave the code as it is.

Comment: Just what I was looking for, thanks. Yes, I've been debating whether or not to expose the function directly. Mainly, it gives me the option to run preliminary code before invoking the Actionable (such as setting some state eg. toggling a lock, or similar), but so far I've been able to handle everything from inside the function itself, so I may be able to do as you suggest.